# Using EL functions

Tags: java, html, validation, jsp, el

I am trying a simple validation program with JSP and EL (not that I need the functionality itself, but just to learn the ropes of JSP). I set the prefix as "mine" and validate is a function which checks if the two `String` inputs are equal to `"admin"` and `"password"` using the `String.equals` method. However, I get `"false"` (unexpected) from the first code block and `"true"` (as expected) from the second.

What's going on?

The following code is in my jsp file.

```
<c:set var="a" value="admin"/>
<c:set var="b" value="password"/>
${mine:validate(a, b)}
```

OR

```
${mine:validate("admin", "password")}
```

Here is the full code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="mine" uri="Functions"%>
<html>
<body>
<c:set var="a" value="admin"/>
<c:set var="b" value="password"/>
${mine:validate(a, b)}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that the actual full code of the JSP?  Variables you create with c:set have scope like anything else.

Comment: Here is the full code (sorry I don't know how to format this)

    <%@ taglib prefix="mine" uri="Functions"%>

    <html>

    <body>

    <c:set var="a" value="admin"/>

    <c:set var="b" value="password"/>

    ${mine:validate(a, b)}

    </body>

</html>

Comment: '<%@taglib prefix="c"
          uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>'  ?

Comment: Wait a minute, no that was not there. How silly of me! Thank you

Comment: I don't know how to do that as it shows up as just a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot select a best answer so I will have to quote the comment left by [Affe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331052/affe):

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```